# Geogebra unable to solve equation with pre-defined function

Tags: exponential-function, math-software

**Disclaimer**

*The issue seems to be due to restricting the function on an interval, even though the solution is within the given range. It seems to be a bug in Geogebra, and I have submitted a ticket for the developers.*

*Leaving this question un-deleted as documentation.*

---

**Background**

I have a function $f(x)$ defined by the `FitExp` command, restricted by $0 \leq x \leq 50$.

I want to solve $f(x) = 100$, and I've tried both the `Solve` and `NSolve` commands, but they both yield $?$ as the answer. See image below.

**Question**

Is there another command I should be using for this, or is there some other input needed before this will give the answer?

**NOTE**

All commands in CAS were entered after all the commands in the Algebra view. Meaning, $f(x)$ was defined before I tried to use `Solve` and `NSolve`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Im using the desktop version of geogebra*. Defining your function in the algebraic view

$$f(x):=6.17 e^{0.1 x}$$

by typing in the bar

```
f(x)=6.17 e^(0,1 x)
```

and after using the command in the CAS view

```
Solve[f(x)=100,x]
```

I get the answer

$$\left\{x=10\ln\left(\frac{10000}{617}\right)\right\}$$

Indeed it also works with the command

```
Solve[f(x)=100]
```

Probably it doesnt work for you because you had restricted $f$ in $[0,50]$ (I dont know how to do this, but I can see it in your picture).

Comment: Strange. I started a new window, and doing it all the same, now it works. I've created an issue for the Geogebra developers. Could be some strange caching issue from a previous session.

Comment: @Alec probably it is because you had $f$ defined only for $x\in[0,50]$, at least it seems so in your picture. How you had restricted $f$ in this domain?

Comment: `f(x) = Function[FitExp[list1], 0, 50]` followed by `Solve[f(x)=100]` does indeed seem to fail, while leaving out the restriction makes everything work.

Comment: @Alec indeed this is a bug. Well, if you had sent a ticket probably it will disappear in the next version of geogebra :)

Comment: Good observation. I have updated my ticket for the developers. Thanks for your help!